# Using Description environment with cleveref

Tags: cross-referencing, cleveref, description

Is there a way to use `cleveref` to reference the name of an item in a description environment?

For example, if I have

```
\begin{description}
    \item[TEST\label{test}] test
\end{description}
```

I would like to reference it through `\cref{test}` and for the text to be `TEST`.

Comment: Does the solution *have to* be based on cleveref's machinery? If not, would a solution based on the `\hyperlink`/`\hypertarget` mechanism of the `hyperref` package be acceptable?

Comment: @Mico does this mean I would not use `\cref``/`\Cref` to create the reference? Ideally, for consistency purposes, I would like to stick with using the `\cref`/`\Cref` command to create references (whether `cleverref` is used under the hood I have no strong opinions about. From an outcome perspective, if I had to use a different command but had consistent behaviour for all references throughout the document, I would not mind.

Comment: `cleveref` works by greatly extending LaTeX's basic `\label`/`\ref` mechanism. LaTeX associates the argument of `\label` with the *most recently incremented* counter variable. (E.g., each time a `\section` directive is executive, the `section` counter is incremented.) Unlike the `enumerate` list environment, the `description` list environment does not increment a counter variable when an `\item` directive is encountered. You'd have to graft some kind of secondary counter mechanism onto the `list` environment -- and associate the new counters with the description list test items. Ugly...

Comment: @Mico I am also happy to _not use_ the description environment if I can still achieve the same end: a named list item which I can then reference by name.

Comment: If you can use an `enumerate` environment, you (more precisely, `cleveref`) would be all set to go. However, the cross-reference call-out produced by `\cref` would be a number, *not* the implicit or explicit label associated with that number. This is why I was thinking about employing the `\hyperlink`/`\hypertarget` mechanism.

Comment: Okay then that sounds good to me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building on the discussion led in the preceding comments, here's a solution that employs the `\hypertarget`/`\hyperlink` mechanism of the [hyperref](https://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) package to create cross-references that show text strings rather than numbers.

The commands `\hypertarget` and `\hyperlink` both take 2 arguments. `\hypertarget` creates a target; the first argument becomes the internal name of the target, and the second determines what's shown in the document. `\hyperlink` creates a *link* to the target created by `\hypertarget`. The first arguments of `\hypertarget` and `\hyperlink` must coincide, while the second arguments needn't, as is also shown in the following MWE (minimum working example).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks,linkcolor=blue]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\begin{description}
    \item[FOO] \dots
    \item[\hypertarget{list:test}{\textbf{TEST}}] \dots
    \item[BAR] \dots
\end{description}
As was demonstrated in the \hyperlink{list:test}{TEST} item of the preceding list, \dots
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hmm, I getting these errors:
`Undefined control sequence. ...m[\hypertarget{lampstate}{\textbf{State}}]`
`Use of \\smash doesn't match its definition. ...m[\hypertarget{lampstate}{\textbf{State}}]`

Comment: @DavidPoxon - Did you load the `hyperref` package?

Comment: I have the following `\usepackage[hyperfootnotes=false]{hyperref}`

Comment: @DavidPoxon - My divination skills are, sadly (but probably not surprisingly), utterly worthless. Showing me some tiny, unconnected text fragments is a fail-safe way of exposing this weakness. Sorry. I do know that my MWE compiles. If your program doesn't compile, it must be because it differs in one or more important aspects from mine. Which document class do you employ? What kind of `description` environment do you employ?

Comment: @DavidPoxon If you also use cleveref, you have to load hyperref and cleveref in correct sequence (cleveref last).

Comment: I load `cleveref` after `hyperref`. I created a new document in Overleaf and used the same preamble in my document - this solution works. I'm not sure why it's not working in my document.

Comment: You may also have a look at the (very advance) package [enumitem-zref](https://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem-zref).

Comment: @Mico I am using `enumitem` version `3.9` and `expdlist` of unknown version. I am using the `book` document class.

Comment: @DavidPoxon - The `expdlist` package appears to have been updated most recently in 1999. (Hey, it was a fine year! I remember it well.) I would strongly recommend that you consider employing the (much newer and still actively maintained) [enumitem](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) package to modify the appearance of `description`-type list environments. If you need help transitioning from `expdlist` to `enumitem`,  feel free to post a new query focused on that particular issue.

Comment: @Mico I am sorry - at a second glance, I misspoke. I _only_ have `enumitem` installed.

Comment: @DavidPoxon - I guess you really, really don't like to part with information freely. So we've confirmed that your document loads the `enumitem` package. Now: What do you *do* with its machinery? Do you modify the `description` environment directly (and, if so, how), or do you create a bespoke `description`-like environment with special properties? As I mentioned earlier, my divination skills are worthless. Hence, do *not* assume that I will be able to guess out of nowhere what's going on in your document.

Comment: @Mico I think this is the frustrating part - as far as I'm aware, I haven't modified the `description` environment in any way (in fact, this is the _one and only_ place I use it in my document.) I have stopped a number of files from being imported, and I have finally got your solution to work! I will reincorporate each document and see which one causes things to fail. :)